# Можно ли автоматизировать padding в конце структуры?

Tags: c++, макрос

В компиляторе есть флаг `-Wpadded`, который выдает предупреждения, если компилятор вынужден в целях выравнивания добавлять память к объявленным в структуре полям.

> Warn if padding is included in a structure, either to align an element
>   of the
>              structure or to align the whole structure.  Sometimes when this happens it is possible
>              to rearrange the fields of the structure to reduce the padding and so make the
>              structure smaller.

**Вопрос:** *Можно ли сделать макрос (не требующий ручного подсчета байт) для добавления поля, хотя бы  в конец структуры, с целью подавления этих сообщений?*

Например, хотелось бы писать что-то в таком духе:

```
struct x {
  int a;
  char c;
  TAILPAD;
};
```

В данном случае макрос `TAILPAD`  должен расширяться в текст

```
char _padding_[3]
```

Вариант с разумным числом аргументов макроса (а также любое другое решение, не требующее чрезмерного ввода символов (а тем более написания скриптов, редактирующих исходник)) также вполне подойдет.

Comment: Может просто не включать это предупреждение? Заметьте, что `-Wpadded` это отдельное предупреждение, которое обычно включают временно для получения подробной диагностики.

Comment: @VTT, тогда я не стал бы набивать столько букв

Comment: Так и что же мешает использовать этот флаг по мере надобности?

Comment: @VTT, так исторически сложилось (в данном случае скрипты сборки править не будут)

Comment: офтоп: это у вас кросплатфома?

Comment: @Cerbo, да, компилируется код для микропроцессора

Comment: Сразу скажу. Некоторое время я размышлял над этой задачкой. К сожалению, сразу приходящий на ум макрос `PAD(LongestType, LastType)` не годится, поскольку не известно выравнивание последнего поля с `LastType`

Comment: думаю всем, кто это читает так и хочется ответить, что нельзя или что не стоит свеч, но самому очень хочется, найти/услышать какое-то хитрое решение...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, вот и я сначала сказал, что что-нибудь придумаю, а потом застрял...

Comment: А можно уточнить вопрос, вам надо выравнивать каждое поле структуры? НАпример struct { short j; char k; }; должна выглядеть как { short j; char pad1[2]; char k; char pad2[3]; } или {short j; char k; char pad[1]; } ? С первым вариантом еще можно придумать кровавый макрос, но это раздует размеры стрктур

Comment: Глобальная цель -- чтобы при включенном флаге `-Wpadded` сообщений не было. Понятно, что размеры структуры меняться не должны (т.е. ничего, кроме естественного padding-а, который делает компилятор в структуре появляться не должно). А также, трудоемкость подхода не должна превышать трудоемкости "ручного подсчета" размера концевого паддинга (сейчас именно это и делается)

Comment: Может, макрос для вставки каждого поля? `FIELD(char,a)`, который развернется в `char  a; char a_padding[3];`?

Comment: На первый взгляд, громоздко будет выглядеть, надо обдумать с коллегами

Answer (score 3):

> Интересно не упаковать поля, а дополнить структуру до подходящего для выравнивания размера.

Компилятор обычно это и делает, просто -Wpadded заставляет его об этом предупреждать, дабы программист сам разбирался со своими выравниваниями. Писать подобные макросы — это фактически выполнять работу компилятора за него. Дабы не изобретать велосипед можно явно отключить это предупреждение для отдельных структур:

```
#define AUTO_PADDING_START \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push"); \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wpadded\"")

#define AUTO_PADDING_END \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")

AUTO_PADDING_START;

struct  S {
    int a;
    char c[1];
};

AUTO_PADDING_END;
```

Ответ тоже из серии обходных путей, но для задачи «не отключать предупреждение глобально, но выравнивать некоторые структуры автоматически», пожалуй, хватит...

Comment: Хорошая идея. Надо будет посмотреть, какие конкретно слова в том компайлере писать.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы погасить пердуперждение -Wpadded, достаточно в конец дописать прагму pack

```
struct x {
  int a;
  char c;
  #pragma pack(1)
};
```

Срабатывает как в C, так и в C++

Comment: это просто отключает паддинг аналогично `__attribute__((packed))`, что может быть фатально на контроллерах...

Comment: Вопрос не об этом. Интересно не упаковать поля, а дополнить структуру до подходящего для выравнивания размера.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону alignas (с++11) и _Alignas (C11).

Comment: @BwanaTheMaster, это не подавляет предупреждение, а напротив провоцирует его...